# How to access for-each loop variable in other class

Tags: java

I am a a newbie to java. I am learning to use for-each loop for iterating over arraylist.

```
  for(String s:list){
my code
}
```

I want to access variable s in another class of same package. Event after making method static I am not able to do so.

I also tried by initializing variable as below:

```
      static String s=null;

    for(s:list){
    my code

}
```

This code is also not working. Please help me to know correct way to access variable 's' in another class

Comment: Then simply send it as a parameter of your other class' method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pass the variable to another class, pass the variable as an agrument to that class's method.

Eg:-

```
Class2 class2 = new Class2();
for(String s : list){
    class2.method(s);
}
```

Comment: IMHO this is the better option than making s public.

Answer (score 0):

In the for each loop in java you are creating temporary variables.

```
for (String s:list) {
  System.out.println(s);
}
```

and this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
  String s = list.get(i);
  System.out.println(s);
}
```

are equivalent. In both cases you cannot access the variable s outside the for loop, which means, that you cannot access it even in the same class, let alone access it outside the class somewhere else. If you want to have access to each element of the list outside the file, why don't you use the list for this reason? Where do you get the list from? I can think of two places you are taking it from:

1. from inside the function

This means you create the list inside the function, which would mean, that you cannot access the list outside the function. If you need the elements of the list in another class, you will have to put them into a class variable (an array or again a list)

```
class MyClass {
ArrayList<String> classVariableList;

function myFunction() {
  //your list was created here
  classVariableList = list;
  for (String s:list) {
    //your code
  }
}
```

2. from a class variable/a parameter

In this case I would recommend you to use this variable also for the other class.

static:

Since you tried to make a variable static to access it outside your class: static only means, that a variable has the trait to be "once per class". This is most commonly used in class variables, which do not have to exist once for every instance of the class. This has nothing to do with where you can access the variable/function/... .

However you can use static in your example as well. Depending on how you want to access the elements of the list in the other class, it might even be a good idea.

When you need more than one lists (e.g. once for every instance you make of your class), then you should not use static. In this case you will have to make the list in every object and access it with:

```
instanceOfMayClass.classVariableList
```

If you only need this one place to access the elements of the list outside your function, then you can make the class variable static (e.g. when you do not update this list frequently and it is shared amongst all instances of your class). in this case you can access the list in the other class by typing

```
MyClass.classVariableList
```

Answer (score -1):

To access a field from another class instance, you need a variable storing an *instance* of that Class and access the (`public`) field by using `varName.fieldName`.

If the field is a static member of the class, simply write `ClassName.fieldName`

Comment: Exposing object data via public fields is not a good idea.

Answer (score -1):

Your public/static solution is the wrong direction. Exposing a local variable publicly at class level in order to make it available to a single other object class would reduce the encapsulation provided by your class, which is bad.

The solution here would be passing the variable via a method call:

```
public class ListProcessor {

    private StringProcessor stringProcessor;

    public ListProcessor() {
        stringProcessor = new StringProcessor();
    }

    public process(List<String> values) {
        for(String value : values){
            stringProcessor.process(value);
        }
    }
}

public class StringProcessor {
    public process(String value) {
        System.out.printf("Processing: %s%n", value);
    }
}
```

EDIT: note that you *can* use an instance or static field as loop variable, although it is usually bad practice to do so:

```
public class FunWithFors {

    private static final int FOREVER = 42;
    private int instanceCounter = 25;
    private static int staticCounter;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        useStaticCounter();

        FunWithFors instance = new FunWithFors();
        instance.useInstanceCounter();
    }

    private static void useStaticCounter() {
        System.out.println("Count from 0 to 3 using static counter");
        for (; staticCounter <= 3; staticCounter++) {
            System.out.println(staticCounter);
        }
    }

    private void useInstanceCounter() {

        System.out.println("Using instance counter:");

        System.out.println("Count down to 20");
        for (; instanceCounter >= 20; instanceCounter--) {
            System.out.println(instanceCounter);
        }

        System.out.println("Count from 1 to 5");
        for (instanceCounter = 1; instanceCounter <= 5; instanceCounter++) {
            System.out.println(instanceCounter);
        }

        System.out.println("Count from 1 until forever");
        for (instanceCounter = 1; ; instanceCounter++) {
            if (instanceCounter == FOREVER) {
                System.out.println("Cheat by breaking out of the iteration");
                break;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Loop endlessly");
        for (; ; ) {
            System.out.println("Help! I'm stuck here");
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Count from 0 to 3 using static counter
0
1
2
3
Using instance counter:
Count down to 20
25
24
23
22
21
20
Count from 1 to 5
1
2
3
4
5
Count from 1 until forever
Cheat by breaking out of the iteration
Loop endlessly
Help! I'm stuck here
Help! I'm stuck here
Help! I'm stuck here
Help! I'm stuck here
Help! I'm stuck here
Help! I'm stuck here
Help! I'm stuck here
(ad infinitum)
```

It would also be possible to access the current value of a counter from another class either by making it non-private or via a getter. However, as pointed out, this is not good practice.

Comment: ThisClass -> StringListProcessor

Comment: @SteveSmith tnx, rename blooper! :-D